# Why does the compiler complain about borrowing a field as immutable even though my function does not access that field in any way?

Tags: rust, ownership-semantics

I am trying to program an application that listens for requests on a socket and then adds them onto a queue to be processed. Part of my code goes as follows:

```
pub struct Middleware {
    listener: TcpListener,
    queue: Vec<String>,
    servers: Vec<String>,
}

impl Middleware {
    pub fn run(&mut self) {
        for stream in self.listener.incoming() {
            let mut stream = stream.unwrap();
            let mut buffer = vec![0u8; 512];
            stream.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();
            self.queue.push(String::from_utf8(buffer).unwrap());
        }
    }
}
```

Yet if I try to abstract some of the code in `run()` into a function (literally just copy/paste):

```
impl Middleware {
    pub fn run(&mut self) {
        for stream in self.listener.incoming() {
            let mut stream = stream.unwrap();
            self.handle_client(stream);
        }
    }

    fn handle_client(&mut self, mut stream: TcpStream) {
        let mut buffer = vec![0u8; 512];
        stream.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();
        self.queue.push(String::from_utf8(buffer).unwrap());
    }
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because `self.listener` is also borrowed as immutable
--> src/lib.rs:21:13
   |
19 |         for stream in self.listener.incoming() {
   |                       ------------- immutable borrow occurs here
20 |             let mut stream = stream.unwrap();
21 |             self.handle_client(stream);
   |             ^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
22 |         }
   |         - immutable borrow ends here
```

From what I understand, `self.listener.incoming()` actually borrows not only the listener "field" but the entire struct. And then, as we cannot have any mutable borrow simultaneously with an immutable borrow, the compiler complains. However, I have to make `self` mutable in `handle_client()`, otherwise I cannot push anything on its queue.

I have been thinking about how to structure the code differently to overcome this problem but can't seem to find a solution without changing my `Middleware` struct (as in removing some fields, etc).

Is it possible to somehow structure the code to use a function (like in my second code snippet)?

Comment: On the contrary; it [forces you towards adding *more* abstraction](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=5b91833c40ae264927688af0d0ce3efe&version=stable).

Comment: @Shepmaster So if I understand it correctly, in your code `handle_client()` borrows `self.queue` which is not a problem vs borrowing just `self` which was the problem in my code (because it is the "parent object" of borrowed `self.listener`? ) ?

Comment: As discussed in the linked duplicates, Rust can only tell that you are performing disjoint borrows of a struct's member inside of a *single* method. The `run` method now sees that you are borrowing `self.listener` and `self.queue` and that those are disjoint — the call to `handle_client` cannot possibly modify `self.listener`.

Comment: Ok I think I got it thank you so much